# C++ Filteration using lazy iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

```
template<typename Iterator>
    struct Range {
        using LazyIterator = Iterator; // required for accessing the used Iterator type from other locations
        Iterator m_begin;
        Iterator m_end;
        auto begin() { return m_begin; }
        auto end() { return m_end; }
    };

    template<typename Iterator>
    Range(Iterator, Iterator) -> Range<Iterator>;    
 template<typename Iterator, typename Callable>
        struct FilteringIterator : Iterator {
            Callable callable;
            using OriginalIterator = Iterator;
            using t = typename OriginalIterator::value_type;
            FilteringIterator(const Iterator begin, Callable callable):Iterator(begin),callable(callable){}
            Iterator &get_orig_iter() { return ((Iterator &)*this); }
            auto operator*() { return callable(*get_orig_iter()); }
        };
auto filter = [](auto action) {
    return [=]( auto &container) {
        using Container = std::decay_t<decltype(container)>;
        using Iterator = typename Container::iterator;
        using actiontype = decltype(action);
        using filter_iterator = FilteringIterator<Iterator, actiontype>;
        return Range{filter_iterator{container.begin(),action}, filter_iterator{container.end(),action}};
    };
};
```

I need a lazy iterator that will traverse over a range and filter it lazily. 
For example

```
auto v = std::vector<double>{};
    auto odd_gen = views::odds();

    for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
        v.push_back(odd_gen() * 2.5);
    // v contains {2.5, 7.5, 12.5, 17.5, 22.5} here

    new_line();
    for(auto a : v | filter(greater_than(15))) // filter is applied lazily as the range is traversed
        std::cout << a  << std::endl;
// print { 17.5, 22.5} here
```

but it prints

{0,0,0,0,17.5,22.5}

I want it to only print 17.5, 22.5

how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code never skips elements, it just transforms them. You need to make sure that when the `operator*()` is invoked, it starts by advancing the iterator while `callable` returns `false`, and only then return the value pointed to by the `Iterator`.

There are corner cases though you have to take care of. If the input ends with elements that don't match the filter, then you run into a problem. You also need to skip over all filtered out elements when `operator++()` is called. And also think about the case where the filter would not match any elements of the input; in that case you must ensure that `begin()` is equal to `end()`.

Comment: Tho, could you please elaborate on the last part a bit more. how can I ensure that my iterator doesn't over increment and cause a crash? Any hint guiding me to right would be appreciated

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulWahabShafiq: every time you manipulate the iterator, which is in `operator*()` and `operator++()`, but also when calling `begin()` (or in `FilteringIterator`'s constructor), you have to advance past any elements that don't match the filter. If you do so, the iterator is guaranteed to either always be pointing to a matching element, or be equivalent to `end()`. Once it's pointing to `end()`, then the `for`-loop will exit of course.